# Uploading files to GCS using Multithread keeps running

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Am trying to upload 36k+ CSV files to GCS from a java application.
This application is hosted as an appengine in the same GCP.

As the number of files are more, am using parallelStream.foreach in java to upload the files.

```
void createFiles()
    {
        try {
            Map<Integer, FileDetail> collection = GetFiles();
            collection.getValue().entrySet().parallelStream().forEach((entry) -> {
                try{
                    createFileInGCS();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOG.error("Error occurred while creating FilesInGCS : " + e.getMessage());
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error occurred while creating files : "+ e.getMessage());
            throw new CustomException("Unable to process files");
        }
    }


    public void createFileInGCS()
    {
        try {
            String fileName ="file_" + fileId + ".csv";
            String gcsBucket = config.getGcsBucket();
            var blobId = BlobId.of(gcsBucket, fileName);
            var blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("text/plain").build();
            var storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(config.getProject())
                    .build().getService();
            storage.create(blobInfo, csvContent.getBytes());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            LOG.error("Storage failed with exception :"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The application is failing, as the number of files(based on external factor) to be stored has increased recently.The whole process of storing runs for  Following are the logs of appengine

**ERROR: onFailure exception: com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: Panic! This is a bug!**

**Storage successful for fileId 46010**

**ERROR: onFailure exception: com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: Panic! This is a bug!**

**Storage successful for fileId 46192**

Note : **ERROR: onFailure exception: com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: Panic! This is a bug!** - This log is observed from the time the appengine start to act on the request

These logs are observed for a while and then we start to receive

**Storage failed with exception :Broken pipe**

**Storage failed with exception :Remote host terminated the handshake**

Later which the application stops

I also tried batching the collection into 10 equal parts, but the strange behaviour is every batch (~3k files) is completing in 4mins except for the last batch, which keeps running for more than an hour and fails with the same error logs.

**Storage failed with exception :Broken pipe**

**Storage failed with exception :Remote host terminated the handshake**

Can someone helps us on, is there a better way to bulk upload these files to GCS. Tried StorageBatch from GCS, but it doesnt have a create option.

Comment: I'm not a Java expert, but regarding GCP, an effective approach for handling GCS writing is to enumerate all the files that need to be transferred to GCS in a Pub/Sub queue. Then, utilize a Cloud Run Job (not a service) to process each file, limiting the job to `x` number of workers.

Comment: Why don't you create your storage service in a singleton? a config.getStorageService() could solve your issue.

Comment: There is a limit to how many HTTP egress data streams are useful. That number is around 4 egress data transfer connections to the Internet. Trying to do a large number of parallel object uploads will actually slow you down and as you found, crash your application. Transfer one object at a time and go have dinner.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere We tried the singleton approach, but that dint help us either :(

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community for the benefits of others

---

As mentioned by @John Hanley:

> There is a limit to how many HTTP egress data streams are useful. That number is around 4 egress data transfer connections to the Internet. Trying to do a large number of parallel object uploads will actually slow you down and as you found, crash your application. Transfer one object at a time and go have dinner.